# Append Linked Tables Into One Table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have three linked tables in my MS Access Database, and I am trying to run just one query to append them all into a master table, rather than creating a separate query for each one.

Can someone give me an example code using generic table names to show how I would union or join these table with query code?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6

Comment: @Nic3500 thats for the response, I was kind of looking more for example code as I've already looked at that page before, thanks.

Comment: You have access (no pun intended!) to videos and tutorials on the web, SO users are expected to do research, and ask specific questions.  That one is too broad.

Comment: `SELECT a.*, b* FROM table1 AS 'a' JOIN table2 AS 'b' ON 'a.fieldname' = 'b.fieldname'`
As mentioned above: Ask a specific question, check tutorials etc. Tell us what code you have so far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [TableA].*
FROM TableA
UNION
SELECT [TableB].*
FROM TableB;
etc.
```

You can do a `SELECT * INTO  NEWTABLE` . . .

You can do all kinds of things.  Google is your best friend.